# JSF <h:dataTable> columns settings?

Tags: jsf, datatable

I use  in JSF, but names seems from top to bottom. I want to see them like matrice. Pictures are below. 
This is picture when this code run:

[image]

But I want to see it:

[image]

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.persons()}" var="myvar">
    <h:column>
       #{myvar.name} 
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 1):

A `dataTable` is not really the right tool for the job. It's better to use a `panelGrid`. There you can specify how many columns to render its child components. So in your case 4:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
  <c:forEach items="#{bean.persons()}" var="myvar">
    <h:outputText value="#{myvar.name}"/>
  </c:forEach>
</h:panelGrid>
```

As it will create a column for each component, use the `outputText` component to render your text.

But, if you really want to stick with a `dataTable`, you could give it a class (for example `class="myTable"`), and use CSS to style it to 4 columns:

```
.myTable * { display: block; }
.myTable tr { width: 25%; float: left; }
```